# Error saving entity with a @OneToOne relationship (relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST)

Tags: jpa, entity, eclipselink

this is my database where each User (tab. **users**) has its Role (tab. **userroles**), with a relationship one to one. The foreign key is "**user id**" in tab userroles.

[image]

when i try to persist the entity User (eclipselink), i get the error message :

```
Error saving entity User{id=0, username=tom.black@mydomain.it, email=tom.black@mydomain.it, password=mypassword, userRole=UserRole(id=null, role=admin, userId=0)}
jakarta.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: UserRole(id=null, role=admin, userId=0).
```

entity **User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;
  // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
  @Column(name = "email")
  private String email;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;
  

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private UserRole userRole;
```

entity **UserRole**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userroles")
@Data
@ToString(doNotUseGetters = true)
public class UserRole implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Size(max = 45)
  @Column(name = "role")
  private String role;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int userId;


  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  @ToString.Exclude
  private User user;
```

the **save** method :

```
...
save(aUser);
..

public void save(Object entity) throws Exception {
    EntityManager em = getFactory().createEntityManager();
    try {
      EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
      try {
        t.begin();
        em.persist(entity);
        t.commit();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error saving entity " + entity, e);
      } finally {
        if (t.isActive()) {
          t.rollback();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
  }
```

I think the mapping is correct, but the error occurs..
i also use lombok library

**UPDATE ----------------------------------------------**

in entity **User** i set :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private UserRole userRole;
```

in entity **UserRole** :

```
  @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable=true, updatable=true)
  private User user;
```

but above all, I set the persistence code like this :

```
newUser.getUserRole().setUser(newUser);  /* <--- (add this) */
em.persist(newUser);
```

Comment: The user instance that you are calling persist on has a reference to a UserRole that doesn't exist in the database. JPA requires providers to thrown an exception in this case as you have not specified what should happen with that UserRole. JPA has clear requirements on what happens to objects passed in on persist/merge, and has to figure out what to do with entities they might reference. If you are expecting this to just work, it is likely that you should be putting the cascade.PERSIST option on the User.userRole mapping so that JPA will persist the userRole when you call persist on user.

Comment: hello,.. UserRoles is an entity and refers to a table ( @Table(name = "userroles") ) .. it is no correct?

Comment: You'll want to look over tutorials that might explain mapping options, but your mapping itself is fine - it is your expectations of what should happen when you give the persist method a user instance that are wrong. Unset the user->user role reference, and this will work no problem. You can then persist the UserRole with a reference to the user, call persist on the userRole and it will work. Or you can just add the CascadeType.PERSIST to the user->UserRole mapping and have JPA automatically call persist on your userRole for you.

Comment: Another unrelated thing that comes to my attention is the use of `insertable = false` element in `@OneToOne` annotation on `UserRole` entity. Why do you understand that `user_id` column on `userroles` table shouldn't be populated by the provider?

Comment: I have to first persist the user, and then get its ID, then save the UserRole with the ID found..
..and of courses, when i load a User, i have to load also its UserRole

Comment: You need to set the UserRole.userId property manually only because of the way you mapped it to be the one that controls the User_Id column. If you made it insertable/updateable=false and had the relationship be writeable, JPA would set the fk column for you from the mapping - and you'd be able to cascade the persist  across the relationship on one side or the other. Try @Mauricio Buffon's answer. The int property isn't necessary.

Comment: i made a post with more details.. if possible.. could you see there?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199951/jpa-onetoone-and-onetomany-relationships-to-save-entities

Comment: You made the problem even more complicated there, adding in a RolesPermission into the mix but mapped even more.. off from what has been mentioned. Focus on User-UserRole and make that work as UserRole-RolesPermission is the same issue, so will have the same solution (or options).

Comment: i made an update to the code (as above) .. i have also added this :
newUser.getUserRole().setUser(newUser); 
and the code works.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @chris points out in his comments, the `User` object you're calling `EntityManager#persist` on has a initialized reference to `UserRole`.

This can be seen in the log you submitted:

```
Error saving entity User {
  id=0, 
  username=tom.black@mydomain.it, 
  email=tom.black@mydomain.it, 
  password=mypassword, 
  userRole=UserRole(id=null, role=admin, userId=0) <= here!
}
```

You can solve this error: 1) leaving the reference `null` or 2) include the `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` element in your annotation.

Nevertheless, your code still has some minor issues:

1. Remove the duplicated mapping for `user_id` column in `UserRole` entity. I don't think it is possibly to even start the application with duplicated mappings.
2. Remove the `insertable = false` element from `@JoinColumn` on `UserRole.user` property. Using this annotation, you won't be able to persist `UserRole` objects.
3. Be cautious using the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in `UserRole` entity. Instead of using `CascadeType.ALL` on your annotations, what if you first identify where you are going to need a cascade operation? Kind of what we've done previously.

They would look more or less like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String username;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String password;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private UserRole userRole;

    /* constructors, getters and some setters */
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "userroles")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String role;
    /* private int userId; <== remove this */
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false)
    private User user;

    /* constructors, getters and some setters */
}
```

Comment: hello, if i remove 
private int userId; in UserRole entity
so I can't set the user id to specify the relationship

Comment: The relationship would be "translated" to the `private User user` property in `UserRole` entity. I mean, that's what the annotation `@OneToOne` is doing over there; it tells the provider that there's a foreign key in `userroles` table referencing the `user` table and that it maps to an `User` entity.

Comment: i made a post with more details.. if possible.. could you see there?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199951/jpa-onetoone-and-onetomany-relationships-to-save-entities