# JPA @OneToOne and @OneToMany relationships to save entities

Tags: jpa, entity, persist

i have to do an entity mapping with this database structure

[image]

these are some sample data

[image]

the purpose is to create new user (tab. **users**), and each user has its own role (tab. **userroles** - `OneToOne` relationship); therefore, when a new user is created, the relationship with the role must also be created;

moreover, there is the permissions table (tab. **rolespermission**), each role has specific permissions ( = `OneToMany` relationship, multiple roles (tab. **userroles**) can correspond to one record in the permissions table (**rolespermission**))

finally, about **userroles** table, I need to make **named queries** that use "`user_id`" field (for authentication scope)

```
@NamedQuery(name = "UserRole.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM UserRole u WHERE u.userId = :userId")
```

entity **User** :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@XmlRootElement
public class User implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
  @Column(name = "email")
  private String email;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;
  
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private UserRole userRole;
```

entity **UserRole** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userroles")
@Data
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "UserRole.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM UserRole u"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "UserRole.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM UserRole u WHERE u.id = :id"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "UserRole.findByRole", query = "SELECT u FROM UserRole u WHERE u.rolePermission.roleName = :role"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "UserRole.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM UserRole u WHERE u.user.id = :userId")})

public class UserRole implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  //  @Size(max = 45)
//  @Column(name = "role")
//  private String role;
//  @Basic(optional = false)
//  @NotNull
//  @Column(name = "user_id")
//  private int userId;
     

  @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable=true, updatable=true)
  private User user;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "role_name", insertable=true, updatable=true)
  private RolesPermission rolePermission;
```

entity **RolesPermission** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rolespermission")
@Data
@ToString(doNotUseGetters = true)
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "RolesPermission.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM RolesPermission r"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "RolesPermission.findById", query = "SELECT r FROM RolesPermission r WHERE r.id = :id"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "RolesPermission.findByPermission", query = "SELECT r FROM RolesPermission r WHERE r.permission = :permission"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "RolesPermission.findByRoleName", query = "SELECT r FROM RolesPermission r WHERE r.roleName = :roleName")})

public class RolesPermission implements Serializable {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;
  @Size(max = 255)
  @Column(name = "permission")
  private String permission;
  @Size(max = 20)
  @Column(name = "role_name")
  private String roleName;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rolePermission", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
```

the mapping seems **(?)** correct in order to create a new user..
when a new user is created

```
em.persist(newUser);
```

all the relative tables are populated with the correct values

**but**, if i update a User

```
em.merge(aUser);
```

in the **users** table, the user is updated, but in the **userroles** table the record **is not updated**, and i have to update also the UserRole

```
em.merge(aUser.getUserRole())
```

.. i don't understand why..

Comment: This is covered in standard JPA tutorials - there are many explaining bidirectional relationships. Your issue here is @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false) - you setup the reference mapping from UserRole->User, but made it read only. So there is nothing to set the user_id foreign key column in your entities. This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173868/error-saving-entity-with-a-onetoone-relationship-relationship-that-was-not-mar that you just expanded on the model without understanding the solution. Make user-UserRole work first

Comment: Key points you haven't shown: how you are creating the UserRole, is it referencing the User you are persisting, and is User referencing it? You must call persist on the UserRole if you want it put into the database and you certainly haven't. this is why it was suggested in your other question that you put the cascade persist options on your mappings so JPA will cascade persist over the reference for you.

Comment: I have updated the above code.. but I can't understand why the role update doesn't work.. wrong mapping?

Comment: You've still got RolesPermission in there confusing things, but you've got persist working, great. The user.userRole mapping only has "cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST" on it, so that is ALL that is cascaded to the UserRole reference. Pick the cascade option you need for the model